# Spring and Hiberante integration. How to persist a command object?

Tags: hibernate, data-binding, spring-mvc

So a simple question but I don't find a right solution. Maybe somebody can give me an idea.
I have a command object com.web.Foo

Assume the expression of the property we are binding to is 'bar.baz', so a nested binding.
If the bar property value is null the Spring is auto-instantiate the Bar object.

If I try to persist the Foo object I got an exception org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: Bar.

What is a right way of persisting command object?

Comment: Please add the (relevant) code of your command object, and the code of your request handler method.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your code I can suggest calling `merge(..)` or `saveOrUpdate(..)`

Comment: It doesn't help me. I've got the same exception.